# How can a Cleric gain extra uses of a domain ability?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, cleric, domains

What options are there for a cleric to permanently gain extra uses of a domain ability normally usable a number of times per day equal to 3 + their Wisdom modifier, aside from alternate favored class bonuses?

Comment: Would increasing Wisdom (through a headband, etc) be a (part of) a valid answer, or are you counting your "3 + their Wisdom" as covering that?

Comment: @Ifusaso, Correct, I consider that to be subsumed in "Wisdom modifier". How to increase one's wisdom should probably be a separate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Believer's Boon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/believer-s-boon/) feat can give you 1 use of that ability, but it's pretty limited. That feat is not really meant for Clerics, but it still works.

Comment: Does that work? Why do you believe that it stacks?

Comment: Sure. You gain the ability to use it Once per day as if you were a lvl1 Cleric. The count is independent of normal usage per day. So doesn't really "stack" as much as is "in addition".

Comment: From my understanding, with this feat, you can actually pick a domain outside of your primary 2 as long as it's still a domain granted by your deity?

Comment: Yes, you are correct @Visfarix, it's not just what OP wanted, but can be used for other stuff.

Answer (score 2):

If your character is Mythic, there is the Mythic Domain path ability for [Hierophants](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-heroes/mythic-paths-paizo-inc/hierophant/).  This will allow you to spend a mythic point once a day to regain all your domain power usages.